# For some reason checking collisions (are there objects in the same coordinates) crashes java in a few seconds

Tags: java

SOLVED
I am working on my own java game engine that has it's own "physics engine", for some reason my new way of checking collisions crashes java?

I am fairly new on java, and I have no idea what is going on, I don't see any problem in the code, nor do I think I would see it.

the complete source is available on [github](https://github.com/ViridiStudios/PointBreakEngine)

the function in gameobject.java:

```java
private void checkAdvancedCollisions(objectManager o, gameObject i){
        if(!i.masterParent.engine_collisions){
            return;
        }
        LinkedList<String> ignore = tag;
        for(gameObject ga : children){
            ignore.addAll(ga.tag);
        }
        for(int xc : new Range(size)){
            for(int yc : new Range(size)){
                if(o.colliding(Math.round(i.x + xc), Math.round(i.y + yc), ignore)){
                    point1(i, o.collidingGA(xc, yc, ignore));
                }
                else if(o.colliding(Math.round(i.x + xc), Math.round(i.y + yc + 1), ignore)){
                    point2 = true;
                    point2(i, o.collidingGA(Math.round(i.x + xc), Math.round(i.y + yc + 1), ignore));
                }
                else{
                    colliding = false;
                    point2 = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the actual checking in objectmanager.java (should work fine):

```java
public boolean colliding(int x, int y, LinkedList<String> ignore){
        for(gameObject i : object){
            if(i.getTag().contains("cursor") || i.getTag().containsAll(ignore)){}
            else{
                if((round(i.x) == x && round(i.y) == y)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public gameObject collidingGA(int x, int y, LinkedList<String> ignore){
        for(gameObject i : object){
            if(i.getTag().contains("cursor") || i.getTag().containsAll(ignore)){}
            else{
                if((round(i.x) == x && round(i.y) == y)){
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and the java completely just stops when using this function, no error messages or anything

Comment: My quick guess is that it's an infinite loop...

Comment: Make `ignore` a `HashSet<String>` as it might grow unendles.

Comment: By the way, `for (int xc : new Range(size))` looks peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Joop Eggen for pointing out that the ignore list may contain endless.
The code was to add all tags of the children to the list, while all gameobjects are children of themselves, causing an endless list.